# Do I need to open the MySQL port for my DigitalOcean LAMP app to work?

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, digital-ocean

I am getting the following error after I first deployed my app: Database connection failed: Connection timed out (2002)

Here is my connecting PHP code:

```
defined('DBSERVER') ? null : define("DBSERVER", "<my_ip_address>"); 
defined('DBUSER') ? null : define("DBUSER", "<db_username>");
defined('DBPASS') ? null : define("DBPASS", "<db_password>");
defined('DBNAME') ? null : define("DBNAME", "<db_name");

private $connection;

function _construct() {
    $this->openconnection();
}

public function openconnection() {
    $this->connection = mysqliconnect(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
    if(mysqliconnecterrno()) {
       die("Database connection failed: " . 
       mysqliconnecterror() . 
       " (" . mysqliconnecterrno() . ")"
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: what will gonna happen when you check connection oop style? `// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} `

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here.  Can you please explain more?

Comment: you're making connection oop style (storing into variable), check connection via variable

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mysql Database on other Machine than yes you have to allow all IP address from mysql configurations and yes you also you have to add firewall exception for Mysql Port in your server.

Comment: I created a firewall and added an inbound MySQL exception but am still getting the same error.

Comment: can you please confirm that your port is accessible by doing check on https://portchecker.co/check

Comment: Strange, it won't let me enter my server IP address.  It only allows me to check my personal one and won't let me overwrite it.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: use this if you want to check your public ip from other netwoek https://www.portcheckers.com/

Comment: strange, I created both an inbound and an outbound rule for 3306 but the portchecker cannot reach it.

Comment: then you have to contact your service provider for that because they might be blocking it,

Comment: and also have you created inbound and outbound rules for TCP/IP protocol?